# proving that a function has a zero

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let $ f : \mathbb{R+} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that satisfies

$f(0) = 0 \;\;\;\;f(1) = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ \forall x \in \mathopen{]}0\,;1\mathopen{[}$, $f(x) > 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall x \in \mathopen{[}1\,;+\infty\mathopen{[}$, $f(x) = 0$

let's define $ g : \mathbb{R+} \to \mathbb{R}\;\;\;\;$ by $\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall x \in \mathopen{[}0\,;+\infty\mathopen{[},\; g(x) = f(x+f(x)) -f(x)$

I would like to prove that $\exists \,c \in \mathopen{]}0\,;1\mathopen{[}$ $: g(c) = 0$

Comment: Hint: By compactness and continuity we have that $f$ attains a maximum on $(0,1)$. Use this to show that $g$ attains both positive and negative values in $(0,1)$ and conclude that $g$ admits a zero in $(0,1)$.

Comment: It would be less confusing and more readable if you use $(0,1)$ instead of $]0;1[$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** As $[0,1]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, the following maximum exists
$$ m= \max_{x\in [0,1]} f(x).$$
Now use again compactness and continuity to get
$$ x_{min} := \min \{ x\in [0,1] \ \vert \ f(x)=m\}$$
and
$$ x_{max} := \max \{ x\in [0,1] \ \vert \ f(x)=m \}.$$
As $f(x_{max})>0$ by assumption, we get that $f(x_{max} + f(x_{max})) < m$ and hence
$$ g(x_{min})= f(x_{max} + f(x_{max})) - f(x_{max}) = f(x_{max} + f(x_{max})) -m < m -m =0.$$
I leave it to you to construct a value where $g$ is positive (you have to use $x_{min}$ and the continuity of $f$). Then by the intermediate value theorem one get's a zero of $g$.